# Word Arrangement Machine Problem

Tags: cipher, explanation

- ***Input***:     All    Indians   Are   My   Brothers   And   Sisters
- ***Step I***:    23    32   12    38    65       17   81
- ***Step II***:   30    70   41    156  328       104   568
- ***Step III***:  568    328 156    104  70  41   30
- ***Step IV***:  20    15  15    9     12  11   10
- ***Step V***:   41    32  33    22     29  28   27
- ***Step VI***:  Sisters  Brothers  My   And  Indians  Are  All

As per the rules followed in the steps given above, answer the following question:

***New Input***: Nothing   Is   Ever   Lost   Other   Than   Change

***Question***: How many words in step VI for the new input appear in the same position as they appear in the input?

Answer:

> 0 because step VI will return: Than Change Lost Other Ever Nothing Is

What is the ***logic behind the re-arrangement in step VI?***

Source: From a local textbook of an institution named 1002105

Comment: Oooh! Great point! But I have noticed it in some places in the textbook and it seems likely that they have themselves picked these from other sources as well, not quite sure though.

Comment: I just found the link to the meta post for [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7260/78801)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer...

Step I:

> Substituting $A = 1, B = 2, ..., Z = 26$, find the sum of all the consonants and subtract the sum of all the vowels, e.g. $"All" = (-1) + (12+12) = 23$.
>
> So the result for the new input would be:
>
> $39, 10, 30, 36, 26, 41, 26$

Step II:

> For each word in the sentence, multiply the previous result by its position in the sentence (starting with 1) and then add its position if they were numbered in reverse, e.g. "All" is the first word in a 7-word sentence, so we take the previous result ($23$), multiply by $1$ and add $7$ to get $30$; for the second word we take $32$, multiply by $2$ and add $6$ to get $70$, etc.
>
> So the result for the new input would be:
>
> $46, 26, 95, 148, 133, 248, 183$

Step III:

> Reorder the results from the prior step in descending order. The results for the new input would now be:
>
> $248, 183, 148, 133, 95, 46, 26$

Step IV:

> Take the sum of the digits of the previous answer, and add its position in the order (starting from 1), e.g. $568$ -> $(5 + 6 + 8) + 1 = 20$, $328$ -> $(3 + 2 + 8) + 2 = 15$, etc.
>
> So the new result is:
>
> $15, 14, 16, 11, 19, 16, 15$

Step V:

> Double each number and add its position in the sequence, e.g. $20 * 2 + 1 = 41$. The new result is:
>
> $31, 30, 35, 26, 43, 38, 37$

That's all I have so far, will update once I figure out the rest.

Comment: I had idea till step 5 but not for step 6. Sorry for missing out on this in my question. I'll add it. But it's on same terms as you have said, though I figured that much myself.

Comment: If you already know the answers for all of the steps you don't need to add it to the question, leave that as part of the puzzle.

Comment: Oh, ok. I cancelled the edit.

Comment: The not-so-helpful solution states "Step VI is the original word for the number." Does this helps you at all?

Comment: There are a potentially infinite number of arbitrary transformations we could do to the numbers in the example that would produce the output. 

I realized now this is the third puzzle you've posted from the same "textbook" that all have ambiguous / nonsensical answers... maybe just stop reading the book. It's not really interesting trying to figure out what the authors were thinking when we've already determined from previous puzzles that they're not following the normal rules of logic.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the book has some errors I agree, but otherwise it's alright. I discuss all the problems here, that's why it looks that way.

Comment: Perhaps this problem from same textbook to which I posted an answer too might change your mind: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116878/pipes-and-tanks-network

Comment: Why would that change my mind? That's yet another puzzle that you believe the textbook is providing the wrong answer.

Comment: But the question is good. Anyways, you took time to look at it, thank you for that. And also, the logical deduction question which first introduced me to you, I was finally able to understand it, all thanks to you (and FlorianF) so you (both) are great :-). Also, I have checked your other posts and I don't know what to say further (mind-blown)!!!